# How to check variables in python module

Tags: python

I have a file with variables

```
//data.txt
M = 100
m = 1
E = 5
j = 1
s = 1
```

I use the following function to load the data into a python script

```
def load_file(path):
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
        print('Parameters file not found.')
        exit()

    module_name = os.path.basename(path).replace('-', '_')
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(
        module_name,
        importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader(module_name, path)
    )
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    sys.modules[module_name] = module
    return module
```

In the main script, the usage would be

```
import sys
import os
import importlib
data = load_file('data.txt')
print(data.M)
```

I can access the variable names with `data.Variable`. The question I have is how do I check if data contains all the variables it should?

Comment: Your first step is ensuring the file has the right data so read it into a dict or however else and ensure the data you require is there from the file. Your task here is to take text and turn it into python variables so validate the text where needed first if that is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if the variables are defined maybe you can use `dir`:

```py
print(set(['E', 'M','j', 'm', 's']).issubset(dir(data))) # Prints True if all variable are defined
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. How do you know wich variable is missing?

Comment: To do that you can iterate over your list of variables `['E', 'M','j', 'm', 's'] ` and check one by one if they are `in dir(data)` and do something if they aren’t

Comment: it is better to use `vars` instead of `dir`

Comment: It's better to use set literal instead of set built from list (`{'E', 'M', ...}`). For one-letter names - maybe even `set('EMjms')` to type less quotes:)

Comment: To find missing values, you can use a set difference (`set(...) - set(vars(data))` or `set(...).difference(vars(data))`. Loop is not needed for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple check whether the element is present in the `dir` output, or not.
Example:

```
if 'E' in dir(data):
  print("E is present")
else:
  print("E is NOT present")
```